# My own message queue/fifo

Tags: c, linux, ipc

Can someone guide me on how to implement my own FIFO application to use is in IPC, I know that I can do this with SHM, socket or using any other sys-v or posix ipc.

The reason I'm looking for this is because I wanna build this fifo with my own specification that will suite my applications with the locking inside this application, so that any application can only call enqueue or dequeue, just like with fifo the kernel will make sure that it's atomic as long as you are writing less than the pipe_buff. I know how to build circular buffer queue but I'm not sure how will I call it from another application, do I need to build an API for it ? or is it something else?

the system is Linux and the language is c.

Comment: please read before voting down the question.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend using POSIX MQ library. They are thread safe and I believe may be persistent. I've used it with a lot of success and it allowed me to focus on solving the problem at hand instead of rolling my own.